# Django Haystack select which fields to search

Tags: django, search, django-haystack

Suppose I have a Person model looking like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True,  null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True,  null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=False, null=False)
```

And a Haystack search index like this:

```
class NoteIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')
    first_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='first_name')
    last_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='last_name')
```

Say the template includes all three fields(firstname, lastname and title). If users should be able to choose in which fields to search for, do I need to build seperate indices for all possible permutations? Or can I narrow down the search to one or two of the three fields?

If so how?

I know that I am able to filter SearchQuerySets using .filter().

```
 SearchQuerySet().filter(first_name='foo')
```

But this filters the set for exact values. Even `__icontains` is limited to one field filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AutoQuery` instead of the standard `filter`:

```py
from haystack.inputs import AutoQuery


SearchQuerySet().filter(first_name=AutoQuery('foo'))
```

https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/v2.4.1/inputtypes.html#autoquery

**EDITED**
In order to run OR query with "haystack" use SQ objects:

```py
from haystack.backends import SQ
from haystack.inputs import AutoQuery

SearchQuerySet().filter(
    SQ(first_name=AutoQuery('foo')) | SQ(last_name=AutoQuery('foo'))
)
```

https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/v2.4.1/searchquery_api.html#sq-objects

Comment: Thank you! Stupid question, because it isn't clear in the documentation: Does it work with word parts? For example, would this filter out firstname="foofoo" when it is hit with AutoQuery('foo')?

Comment: Additionally, this does only solve my problem with being able to search one field. With filter and AutoQuery everything is concatenated by AND. I cannot specify for the search string to be in either first_name OR last_name.

Comment: @1D0BE, in response to your first comment, I think that search for incomplete strings is not the purpose of a full text search system, and by default the backend can't do it (or I don't know how).

Comment: For others coming here from a Google search. You can search for incomplete strings as well by use of Ngramfields and EdgeNgramfields. It can be found here: https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/searchfield_api.html